# Factorial using `for` loop in Kotlin

Tags: loops, kotlin, factorial

With experience of java programming, I started learning Kotlin today. I am playing with the language and found me stuck to find a factorial using `for` loop in kotlin. I managed to do this using `while` loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val reader=Scanner(System.`in`)
    val x: Int = reader.nextInt()
    println(factorial(x))
}

fun factorial(a: Int): Int{
    var ans=1
    var i: Int = a
    while(i>1){
        ans*=i
        i--
    }
    return ans
}
```

Please help me to do this using a `for` loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, the simplest one that comes to mind:

```
fun factorial(num: Int): Long {
    var result = 1L
    for (i in 2..num) result *= i
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't use a for loop, but just as an addition you can also make this shorter, more functional and Kotlin-like using [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

```
fun factorial(num: Int) = (1..num).reduce(Int::times)
```

Or:

```
fun factorial(num: Int) = (1..num).reduce { a, b -> a * b }
```

This is the simplest I can think of.

Edit: This is equivalent to

```
fun factorial(num: Int) = (2..num).fold(1, Int::times)
```

as `reduce` is practically a `fold` starting from the value at index 0.

We start with 2 instead, however 1 would be equivalent as multiplying by one doesn't change the result.

Edit 2: this edit is exactly what holi-java just posted.

Comment: What about 0 factorial? It doesn't seem to work with factorial(0), while the solution using fold does.

Answer (score 2):

there is another **expressive** one by using [Range#fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) and function reference expression, for example:

```
fun factorial(n: Int) = (2..n).fold(1L, Long::times)
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I am so bold to not do it in a for loop,*

Here is a handy one liner recursive function to determine the factorial:

```
fun factorial(a: Int): Long = if (a == 1) a.toLong() else factorial(a - 1) * a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Factorial:**

```
fun factorial(num : Long) : Long {
    var factorial : Long = 1
    for (i in 2..num) {
        factorial *= i
    }
    println("Factorial of $num = $factorial")
}
```

**Factorial using BigInteger variable:**

```
fun factorial(num : Long) : Long {
    var factorial = BigInteger.ONE
    for (i in 2..num) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(num))
    }
    println("Factorial of $num = $factorial")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using recursion:

```
fun factorial(number: Int): Int {
    when (number) {
        0 -> return 1
        else -> return number * factorial(number - 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way :

```
fun factorial (data : Int) : Long {
        var result : Long = 1
        (1..data).map {
            result *= it;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

if you want use BigInteger :

```
fun factorial (data : Int) : BigInteger {
        var result : BigInteger = 1.toBigInteger()
        (1..data).map {
            result *= it.toBigInteger();
        }
        return result;
    }
```